# "connect to server" for KDE

Tags: ssh, ftp, mount, kde, remote

Everybody knows the Gnome program (I can remember the package name right now, or if it's Nautilus itself) that gives us the menu "connect to server" that we can login in a remove ftp, ssh, windows, and much more and mount it very easily. Looks pretty much like expandrive for macos. 
What I need is a tool like that. But for KDE. Anyone knows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [KioFuse](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/KioFuse).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: does it have a GUI?

Comment: MountMan (part of [Krusader](http://enwp.org/Krusader)) or [KDiskFree](https://www.kde.org/applications/system/kdiskfree/)

Answer (score 2):

Use either Konqueror or Dolpin.  For Konqueror, just type the URL in the address bar, e.g. ftp://invalid.com, etc.  For Dolpin, select File->Create New->Create New URL and do the same. Hope that is what you want.

Comment: Nope. Those methods only access ftp servers. The connect to server for gnome I can access ssh, sftp, windows share, and a lot of more must-have stuffs for me.

Comment: @anothertrad: ah, no, that is not the case.  Use the correct protocol type in the UBL, e.g. smb:// for Windows shares, sftp:// for sftp, etc.  Try it!  The protocol types are not hard to find.  Konqueror might be more straight forward if Dolphin is confusing you.

Comment: ok but I need it mounted in a folder so I can do stuff trough the console and other apps.

Comment: awesome! this is what ended up working for me. might be good to edit your answer to make it clearer that you have to click next to where Dolphin lists your current file path in order to bring up the address bar